# Running TestNG tests in Maven fails

Tags: maven, testng

I am trying to run TestNG tests in Maven. here is my configuration:

pom.xml:

```
     <dependencies>
             <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.11</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is the testNG conf file:

```
<suite name="Suite1">
<test name="Test1">
    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="Setup" />
            <include name="Material" />
        </run>
    </groups>

    <packages>
        <package name="coloright.hibernate.*" />
    </packages>
</test>
```

when I run with eclipse - no problem.

when I run with mvn test - all test run successfully, but build failed with error:

suiteXmlFiles is configured, but there is no TestNG dependency

Please help

Comment: If you run in debug mode, the surefire plugin should report the location (in the console) of where its looking for the testng.xml file.  What does it say?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are hitting [this surefire bug](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-161), which contrary to the status [looks to be still open](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-161?focusedCommentId=232528&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-232528).

The bug appears if surefire is unable to find the file specified in `<suiteXmlFile>`.  Could you try just specifying `testng.xml` omitting `src/test/resources` to see if that helps?  The [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#suiteXmlFiles) is silent on how this location is to be specified - whether it should be relative to the base directory or relative to test resources folder.

Comment: omitting the path doesn't help. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @rperez How about the full path: `${basedir}/src/test/resources/testng.xml` - assuming this is indeed the reason for the error?

Comment: it is not a matter of path as the file is found and the tests run. at the ent the maven build fails with the above exception (even though all tests passes)

Comment: I still face the same problem. I see this is a very old post. Can I get a solution if any?
Please correct me if am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this.  Not sure if it would work for you but I do this sometimes, although it seems like its redundant:

```
<suiteXmlFiles>
  <suiteXmlFile>
    ${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/testng.xml
  </suiteXmlFile>
</suiteXmlFiles>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the surefire-testng dependency to your pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
<artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
<version>2.16</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your output folder in build path should be like /target/test-classes.

Also check your pom entry for this and update accordingly:

```
 <testSourceDirectory>src</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>target/test-classes</outputDirectory>
       <resources>
         <resource>
            <directory>src</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```